# How to view more than one image in a jsp page?

Tags: jsp, struts2

I couldn't view more than one image in my jsp page but the action returns more than one image from database.How to view all of that images in my jsp?
My jsp page result.jsp given below.

```
 <%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<html>
   <head></head>
   <body>
     <h1>Struts 2 Dynamic Image Example</h1>
     <img src=" <s:url action='downloadAction' />" />
   </body>
</html>
```

Action class MultipleFileDownloadAction.class is given below.

```
import java.sql.Blob;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.struts2.ServletActionContext;
import org.apache.struts2.interceptor.SessionAware;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class MultipleFileDownloadAction extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware {

    private int id;
    private Map session;
    private String name;
    
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        getText();
        return "success";
    }
    private void getText() throws Exception {
        Blob b;
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/afsaldb","root","applogic");
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select img,name from multipleimg");
        
         ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                
                
                    b = rs.getBlob(1);
                    
                    setName(rs.getString(2));
                    
                      HttpServletResponse response = ServletActionContext.getResponse();
                      response.reset();
                      response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\""+name+"\"");
                      response.getOutputStream().write(b.getBytes(1, (int)b.length()));
                     
                      response.getOutputStream().flush();
                      response.getOutputStream().close();
                 
            }
          }
    
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public Map getSession() {
        return session;
    }
    public void setSession(Map session) {
        this.session = session;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

My struts.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
   "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>

<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
 
    <package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
 
    
    <action name="downloadAction" 
         class="org.MultipleFileDownloadAction">
         <result name="success">result.jsp</result>
    </action>
   </package>
</struts>
```

table in database is given below.
[image]
The output of this program is only showing first image retrieved from database.

please help

Comment: You can't. This makes no sense. Either you download one image, or you download a zip (for example) containing several images.

Comment: There is a lot of confusion in this question. You should start defining *exactly* what you want to achieve logically, then trying, then asking. You can download multiple files in a ZIP, or open multiple images in a JSP using mutliple <img>, or multiple <iframe>, or one image at time by passing the id of the image wanted in the call, and in each case, you are bypassing Struts mechanisms because you should not writing directly to the resposne, but returning a JSP, or a STREAM if you need to show binary data only... how it is now, it's not clear what you want nor why you want it like that. HTH

Comment: Its a image portfolio. I need to view more than one image in my jsp page. @JBNizet ..

Comment: Then the JSP should have N `<img src="..."/>` tags, which will cause N requests to the server, each downloading 1 image. And you shouldn't use `Content-Disposition=attachment` since the goal of this header is to make the browser suggest saving the image to a file, which you don't want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create images in your porject folder and can give path in jsp.

**Step 1:** Create a folder `images` in your project Folder.

**Step 2:** In `MultipleFileDownloadAction.java` Edit to following code

```
public class MultipleFileDownloadAction extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware {

private int id;
private Map session;
private String name;

private List<String> list;
//getter setters...
}
```

in execute method or in `getText()` method change code to following.

```
private void getText() throws Exception {
...
list = new ArrayList<String>();
while (rs.next()) {
byte[] bAvatar;
            try {
                if(rs.getBlob(1)!=null)
                {
       list.add(rs.getString(2));
                    bAvatar = rs.getBlob(1).getBytes(1, (int) rs.getBlob(1).length());
                    setName(rs.getString(2));
                 System.out.println(request.getRealPath("/")+"images\\"+rs.getString(2)+".jpg");
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(request.getRealPath("/")+"images\\"+rs.getString(2)+".jpg"); 
                    fos.write(bAvatar);
                    fos.close();
                    bAvatar=null;
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
  }
  }
```

This will create image in your images folder.

**Step 3:** In result.jsp file

```
<%@taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%>
<table>
<s:iterator value="list" status="userStatus">
    <tr class="<s:if test="#userStatus.odd == true ">odd</s:if><s:else>even</s:else>">
        <td><s:property /></td>
        <td><img src="images/<s:property />.jpg" width="100" Height="100" alt="No image uploaded" /></td>
    </tr>
</s:iterator>
</table>
```

**Example Output:** [Download Code here](https://github.com/prem30488/ImageDatabaseExample/archive/master.zip) - [Project URL](https://github.com/prem30488/ImageDatabaseExample)

[image]

Comment: I did as you said.Its adding images to folder images but not showing in result.jsp page. page is blank.

Comment: did you remove `HTTPresponse` response.addHeader()... etc. code from action class?

Comment: in result.jsp is this line is currect?
<td><img src="images/<s:property />.jpg" width="100" Height="100" alt="No image uploaded" /></td>

Comment: Should we add any value to property tag?

Comment: the list variable is **class variable** in action class with **getter setters**. Did you use it as **class variable**? Also check did you get names in that `list`? These names will be used as image names, and now in jsp you need to provide link to these images in `<img src=""/>`

Comment: right click on browser and see view source and tell me what html are you getting? Also check `System.out.println(list.size())` in code. And tell me how many items are there in list?

Comment: View source is blank.List size is 3

Comment: Thanks a lot man.My return string in execute method was 'none'.Its working now